# Applications don't start in enlightenment WM

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, window-manager, startx, enlightenment

I installed enlightenment on my arch but I experience some rather strange behaviour.

If I start it with `startx /bin/enlightenment_start` I get a black screen and a mouse cursor. The same happens if I do `startx` with a single `exec enlightenment_start` inside.

If I just run `enlightenment_start` (from tty) it starts and I can click around, open file explorer and some settings windows, but nothing more. I can't open xterm or chromium or vim or whatever. Nothing happens.

However, I noticed something weird. If I try to open vim in enlightenment and then log out (i.e. return to the tty; I do not use any graphical login managers), I get the zsh prompt again but get some vimy behaviour. The cursor goes to the top of the screen and starts rewriting some characters there. In some cases I do also see the insert mode indicator.
If I do `ctrl-c` I get "type :q to quit vim". If I type it, it gets written on the screen. I.e. I get some mixed prompt/vim behaviour which I escape only by running `pkill vim` from the outside. Then I get back the working prompt.

I couldn't find anything related neither on SE nor in the official website. According to the arch docs it should work only by installing it and running `startx`.

Any ideas on how to make enlightenment usable?